# Is the conda tool installed in the base environment or out of it?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

When I try to update conda, I was told to execute `conda update -n base conda`, does this mean that the conda tool is installed in the base environment? Or the conda tool is installed out of any environment?

Comment: Are you looking to update all conda packages `conda update --all`, or conda itself `conda update -n base conda`?

Comment: i am trying to update conda itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. On all typical<sup>**1**</sup> distributions it is always installed in the **base** environment.<sup>**2**</sup> One can check all environments with the `conda` package installed with:

```bash
conda search --envs conda
```

It is possible to be installed elsewhere, in addition to **base**, but the **base** copy will be the default when not available in the currently activated environment.

---

<sub>**[1]:** [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution), [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#), and [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) variants.</sub>

<sub>**[2]:** In older Anaconda installations, **base** was previously termed **root**.</sub>